# Algorithm for nesting nesting sets

Tags: algorithm, sorting, set, directed-acyclic-graphs, partial-ordering

I have a large collection of sets, some of which are subsets of each others, like:

```
[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2}, {1, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 6}]
```

I'd like to take this collection and output a DAG of partial order of the subset relations

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} >= {1, 2, 3, 4} >= {1, 2}
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} >= {1, 5}
{2, 6}
```

Is there a way to do this other than comparing all combinations of sets (which is prohibitive when there is a large number of sets). This seems close to a number of set cover problems but, I can't find a problem that this reduces to.

One optimization is to create an inverted index which would help avoid comparing sets that had no common element like `{2, 6}` and `{1, 5}`.

This problem seems related to [Topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) and [Linear Extensions of a partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_extension).

This is nearly a duplicate of [Generate a DAG from a poset using stricly functional programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838779/generate-a-dag-from-a-poset-using-stricly-functional-programming), but I'm open to a solution that is not purely functional.

Comment: [ {1,2,3,4}, {1,2,3}, {1,2}, {1} ]  I doubt is it possible to avoid O(N^2) when the final graph is a complete graph?

Comment: I feel like I should be able to exploit the partial orderablity to do better than that.

Comment: You can start by ordering the sets by size, and going in increasing order, and when looking at the next set you can start comparing it to previous sets in *decreasing* order of size, and if it's a superset of one of them, then it's also a superset of its entire subgraph and you don't need to consider those smaller sets.

Comment: For finding which sets are subsets of a given set, see paper linked from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353100/quickly-checking-if-set-is-superset-of-stored-sets

Comment: Do you aim for a full graph holding all ribs of inclusion? How will you use the DAG after you construct it?